# What is meant by "Curb lane" in American English?

Tags: american-english, vocabulary

I am reading a text about the recent Open Restaurants initiative in the NYC area (following the covid crisis), and they are talking about the ability of restaurant owners to use the "curb lane" to put tables.

Am I right in assuming that "curb lane" means the lane closest to the sidewalk? And is it necessarily the parking lane or can it be any lane, like a normal road lane?

Comment: Have you [searched it up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_outside_lane)?

Comment: This reference contains 'Wide Curb Lane—A travel lane at least 14 feet wide, adjacent to a curb, which allows bicyclists and motorists to travel side-by-side within the same traffic lane'. Pretty definitive for 'curb lane' in general; no caveat about 'parking lane' status. [This article](https://www.journals.elsevier.com/transportation-research-part-a-policy-and-practice/call-for-papers/special-issue-on-the-curb-lane) is far more detailed, but the specification givenmay not be the only 'definition' in use.

Comment: No hard-and-fast rule, but generally it means a parking lane, or perhaps a turn lane or a lane where vehicles wait for passengers.

Comment: Yes, but it's not quite clear. I am not a native English speaker and the notions get more detailed/technical than what I'm reading in the NYC texts, which makes me think that I might be missing something.

Comment: Note in British English it's a `kerb`.